# How to make a REST Webservice call in JAVA?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Currently I have a web service running in a tomcat (http://**localhost:8080/myApp/getUsers**). My web service will accept a json string and then process accordingly. My webservice code is as follows:

```
@Path("/getUsers")
public class UsersWS
{
    @POST
    public Response post(String theRequestJSON)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject aJsonObj = new JSONObject(theRequestJSON);
            String userID = aJsonObj.getString("userID");   
            System.out.println(userID);
        }
    }
}
```

So, my Web service is processing a json string. So now, I need to call the above web service from another JAVA class (with a jsonObject having the userID in request parameter).

How to do it? Shortly, I need to make a web service call from a JAVA class with a JSON object as a request parameter. How to send a json as a request parameter in a request call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post JSON data to a server using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939682/how-to-post-json-data-to-a-server-using-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Jersey: http://jersey.java.net

Here's a good write up on how to use the client:
 http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with

Answer (score 3):

Use native URLConnection or Apache HttpClient to send a HTTP request to the server.And the parameters must passed in `key=value&key2=value2...` format. So you may need to reconstruct the JSON object in that format or using another special parameter name like `data=jsonstring` then parse the json string using some library.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. can you also suggest me some java libraries to post as data=jsonstring in the request?

Answer (score 2):

@George has basically already answered your question, but in terms of JSON processing you may want to also look at Jackson http://jackson.codehaus.org/

This allows you to quickly convert Java objects to JSON equivalents.